# C++ preprocessor + detecting object type and new operation

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, decltype

I currently have this in my code.

```
template<typename T1> class MONEYTRANSFER {
  SOURCEACCOUNT<T1, MONEYTRANSFER> *SourceAccount;               // Line 2
  MONEYTRANSFER(T1 *src) {
    SourceAccount = new (src) SOURCEACCOUNT<T1, MONEYTRANSFER>;  // Line 4
  }
};
```

While I know this isn't that messy, I'd like to at least try and make this look a little nicer.

Is it possible to change line 2, so that 'MONEYTRANSFER' is auto detected by knowing which class it is in?

Is it possible to use a preprocessor for line 4. So I can type `bind(src, SourceAccount);` - without having to type out the type of `SourceAccount (SOURCEACCOUNT<T1, MONEYTRANSFER>)` for the new operation.

I've tried `decltype` but with no luck? Any help will be gratefully appreciated!

Comment: How have you tried `decltype` and what went wrong?

Comment: The finance guys use COBOL style even when writing C++ code??...

Comment: @aschepler: Which expression would you use with decltype in line 2? `*this` is not valid outside members.

Comment: I strongly suspect the code should have been `new SOURCEACCOUNT<T1, MONEYTRANSFER>(src) ;` BTW.

Comment: @aschepler SourceAccount = new (src) decltype(SourceAccount); - I think its because SourceAccount is a pointer. Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: @MichaelBrown: Yes, you could have done `SourceAccount = new(src) decltype(*SourceAccount);`.  (If you really mean to use placement new - but @MSalters raises a good question.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd solve it with a base class mixin:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> class WithSourceAccount
{
  protected:
    SourceAccount<T1, T2>* m_SourceAccount;
    WithSourceAccount(T1* src) 
        : m_SourceAccount(new (src) SourceAccount<T1, T2>())
        { }
};

template<typename T1>
class MoneyTransfer : WithSourceAccount<T1, MoneyTransfer>
{
};
```

Comment: nice try ;), but the code is correct and uses a placement new.

new (src) SOURCEACCOUNT<T1, MONEYTRANSFER>();

would be the 'full' version. i suspect only a preproc will work.

Comment: @MichaelBrown: Ok, made it a placement new. Note that `T2==MoneyTransfer` when instantiated. I'm not sure what you mean by "full" version.